# Can I extract a list of llayout names from a PowerPoint template?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am updating some presentations and it would be helpful to extract a list of the layout names with VBA or another simple method rather than viewing each layout in slidemaster view and typing a list of all the layout names.

The end goal is to make sure that when I apply the new template to old presentations, no new layouts are added.

I want to compare layouts so that my new template contains defined layouts for all the names that are in the old templates.

This is PPT 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
Sub ShowMeStuff()
    Dim oDes As Design
    Dim oLay As CustomLayout

    For Each oDes In ActivePresentation.Designs
        Debug.Print oDes.Name
        For Each oLay In oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
            Debug.Print vbTab & oLay.Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```